# What might "three several" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

The context is from [Sawney Bean](https://www.pascalbonenfant.com/18c/newgatecalendar/sawney_bean.html), which I read recently in an omnibus (I found that link on the spur of the moment):

> ...were afterwards burnt to death in three several fires.

I suppose *three* was meant, but this use of *several* stumped me.  What did it mean back in 1843?

Comment: I just finished reading *Last of the Mohicans* again, and this phrase is used constantly in that classic. Anyone looking for an example of that phrase used in context, I would point them to that book. From chapter eight;
*Three several* times the scout raised his piece in mercy, and as often, prudence getting the better of his intention, it was again silently lowered.

Comment: "Three several" also appears in H.G. Wells' The Time Machine, in describing his sighting of creatures moving up a hill in separate locations. The book was written in 1895.

Comment: @StuartF I upvoted because it is a usage which I am unfamiliar with, regardless if it has been recorded in "a book that gave the different meanings of words!". ELU questions in 2011 were given a lot of leeway back in the day, and users would post relatively easy questions to drum up interest and enthusiasm for a fledging website.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although you don't hear it much at all these days, *several*  used to have the additional meaning of *distinct* or *separate*. It probably just means "three individual fires" in your example, as distinct from three things being burnt in one larger fire.

From TheFreeOnlineDictionary:

> **several**
>   *adj*.
>   2. Single; distinct: *"Pshaw! said I, with an air of carelessness, three several times" (Laurence Sterne).*

Answer (score 8):

The [dictionary entry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/several) for *several* lists the following as one of the definitions:

> Single; distinct: *"Pshaw! said I, with an air of carelessness, three several times" (Laurence Sterne).*

So in this case *several* doesn't mean a relative number (like *a few*), but instead that there were three *distinct* fires.

This unusual definition is related to the [etymology of "several"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=several):

> early 15c., "existing apart," from Anglo-Fr. several, from M.Fr. seperalis "separate," from L. separe (ablative of *separ "distinct"), back formation from separare "to separate" (see separate). **Meaning "various, diverse, different" is attested from c.1500; that of "more than one" is from 1530s, originally in legal use.**

Answer (score 6):

The other contributors are correct. Several here means separate or distinct.

There is one place that I know of that this usage is still common, and that is in the legal term "joint and several liability." This means that if two or more people enter into a contract together that they are liable for the obligations both as a group, and also as distinct individuals.

Comment: +1 for coming up with the only "current" usage I could possibly have brought to mind too.

Comment: I can think of Another "current" usage which I heard (a long time ago) when I received my first degree: we convocands described by the dean as being about to receive our "various and several degrees."